# Batch getting rid of the % from a variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, batch-processing

I have the following code:

```
@echo off
SET A=%%1
echo %A%
pause
```

When I execute it says

```
%1
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I need to get rid of the % from the 1 so it will read

```
1
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Does anyone know what I could do.

Comment: Have you tried to `SET A=1`?

Comment: Change `SET A=%%1` to `SET A=1`.

Comment: Thanks can some on post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set A=1

```
@echo off
SET A=1
echo %A%
pause
```

Result

```
1
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Thanks I will up vote it tomorrow. I think I’ve been to generous with them and have used the all.